# LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var missing in subshell from system(3) call

Tags: c, system-calls

We have a huge client server business application, the server written in C, which does printouts on user request with something like:

```
    system("/usr/local/sisis-pap/cups/bin/lpr ....");
```

The above `lpr` command needs shared libs and to access them the env var `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so the dynamic loader `ld-linux.so` knows where to look for them. The env var is there, i.e. if I do:

```
   p = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
   printf("LD_LIBRARY_PATH env [%s]\n", p==NULL?"":p);
   system("env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

it's printed fine, but in the subshell it's missing.

To be exactly: this is only the case below the application and I was not able to simulate this missing env var with a small C-pgm written on purpose to study this. The application is started as root via cron (i.e. every morning refreshed).

The Linux is a SuSE SLES15.

Any idea what makes `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` disappearing in `system(3)`? The man page does not say this.

Comment: what about other environment variables?

Comment: I modeified the application to start `env` (instead of the `lpr` command) and all othe env vars are fine, **only** `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is missing. This must be somehow a security feature and it's interestingly of **what** this depends as I can't until now simulate this, not even from the root's cronjob.

Comment: `man ld.so` explains in `secure-execution mode` when this var might get to be removed. Are you able to change the `/usr/local/.../lpr` binary?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that the app server runs in `secure-execution mode`, but it does due to a `seteuid(2)` call. With this, I can now also reproduce the problem with a small 10-liner in C. I will answer the question. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reproduced with compiling and running this C-code as `root`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    char *p;

    p = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    printf("getenv(): LD_LIBRARY_PATH env [%s]\n", p==NULL?"":p);
    seteuid(900118);
    printf("effective uid now %d\n", geteuid());

    system("echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH in child: ; env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH");

    exit(0);
}
```

The `seteuid()` sys call makes the app server running in the so called `secure-execution mode` which drops the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from spawned child processes.